# Entity Framework invoke strongly typed stored procedure

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures

Sometimes I need to invoke a stored procedure in my code. Entity Framework will happily do this for me as follows:

```
MyDbContext db = new MyDbContext();
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("EXEC MyProc;");
```

This particular proc doesn't return a value - it just does some updating, so no return value required in this instance.

The problem I have with this is that the reference to the proc is embedded in a string, and I like to avoid this where possible. If I change the name of the proc, add extra parameters, or delete the proc entirely, I won't be aware of the broken reference until I hit that line of code at run-time.

What options do I have for invoking a stored procedure with a strong reference? I have my procedures defined in a database project within the same solution, and I also use a reverse POCO generator (which apparently will also reverse POCO procs, but I haven't tried it yet).

I'm interested to hear the various ways in which others tackle this problem - either with the tools listed above, or with others.

Comment: If if your proc already in EF model you will get a runtime error, not a compile-time error if the procedure's signature has been changed in DB.  You need touch the real database to discover it, right? Yes. Do you touch it during compilation? No.

Comment: My question is, how can I make the procedure reference a compile-time check.